# Passing data between Client Application and Web Application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, wcf

I have a need to create a Web Application that can interact with 3D CAD on an engineers PC. What I was thinking is the [Web Application] would allow them to download a [Windows Service], then use [WCF] on the Server Host, then to the [Web Application]. I would need to pass data back and forth with the ability to fire off some code through the [WCF] to [Windows Service] to [3D CAD]. Is this at all logical? As alternative to [WCF] could [Web Service] be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're on the right track. A WCF service or Web Service is the preferred way to handle communication between client and web applications. And yes, you can use a web service if you prefer, as XML is universally understood regardless of environment or platform.

Comment: As I am currently creating xml for output the Web Service will probably suffice then. Do you know of an example that ties this all together?

Comment: I don't have an example off hand, but if you add the web reference to both applications, you should be able to push and pull information between the applications.

Comment: So just to verify, I create the [Web Service] post up to server host, then make a reference to [Windows Service] and one to [Web Application]? Thats all there is to it?

Comment: @tmax: You would create the web service independent of the two applications, and add a reference to it in the windows app and the web app.

Comment: You should not use web references, or ASMX web services at all. They are now considered by Microsoft to be "legacy technology".  You should use WCF for both clients and services.